# CRC calculation in chunks

Tags: c, crc, crc32

I have a problem when trying to calculate crc in chunks.

This is the code:

```
unsigned int crc32(const unsigned char *buf, int len, unsigned int init){
  unsigned int crc = init;
  while (len--){
      crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc32_table[((crc >> 24) ^ *buf) & 255];
      buf++;
    }
  return crc ^ 0xffffffff;
}

int main(){
        unsigned char buf[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        printf("crc=%08x\n",crc32(buf,10,0xffffffff));

        unsigned int crc = crc32(buf,5,0xffffffff);
        printf("crc_chunk1=%08x\n",crc);
        crc = crc32(buf+5,5,crc);
        printf("crc_chunk1+2=%08x\n",crc);
}
```

the first crc call calculate all 10 bytes,

the second calculate the crc of the first 5 bytes

the third calculate the crc of the last 5 bytes but takes the first 5 bytes crc result as a parameter

Output:

```
crc=9290bbfc
crc_chunk1=06dcaed5 
crc_chunk1+2=d5800060
```

why *crc != crc_chunk1+2*?

I want to combine those chunks so the result will be the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned int crc32(const unsigned char *buf, int len, unsigned int init)
{
    unsigned int crc = init;
    ...
    return crc ^ 0xffffffff;
}
```

The function above starts with `init`, then XORs the result with `0xffffffff`

If you are going to feed the result back in to `crc32` then you have to XOR once more. The second XOR will undo the transform which was done inside `crc32`

```
//one time
unsigned int crc;
crc = crc32(buf, 10, 0xffffffff);
printf("%08x\n", crc);

//two times
crc = crc32(buf, 5, 0xffffffff);
crc ^= 0xffffffff; //undo previous XOR
crc = crc32(buf + 5, 5, crc); //feed back in
printf("%08x\n", crc);
```

or change `return crc ^ 0xffffffff;` to `return crc;` and XOR it with `0xffffffff` before printing.